# React onChange from <select> field not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, render, onchange

I have Parent and Child components. My child component houses a select field with some options and these should update the Parent's state when clicked (onChange), yet they do not. I threw in a debugger into the function which should be running when the `onChange()` occurs, but it never hits it. Where am I going wrong here?

`Parent Component Function`

```
 updateModal(evt) {
  this.setState({ reason: evt.target.value})
 }
```

Passed as a prop like so:

```
<PastSessions
  updateModal={this.updateModal.bind(this)}
/>
```

And then here is my `Child Component` with the select field.

```
<select value={this.props.reason} onChange={this.props.updateModal}>
   <option value='One'>One</option>
   <option value='Two'>Two</option>
   <option value='Three'>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wrap this.props.updateModal in your child component with another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-writing it and it works. Looks like this:

```
  handleUpdateChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      reason: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

passed as props like so

`handleUpdateChange={this.handleUpdateChange.bind(this)}`

called like this

`<select value={this.props.reason} onChange={this.props.handleUpdateChange}>`

Works like a charm

Comment: If I put variable & function names aside, isn't this *exactly* like the code in your original question?

Comment: Yea, it is actually. I had a different answer which included defining it as a self exectuing function with something like `let handleUpdateChange = () => {...}` and then that allowed for the `value` of `select` to be altered, but it wouldn't save when hitting submit, so I changed it to this after a quick google search and it's flawless. You are totally right though, I don't know how this is any different than what I started with...